# Deadlock with asyncio.Semaphore

Tags: python, python-asyncio, semaphore

I have asyncio code that sometimes freezes in a deadlock, which should not be possible in my opinion. As reality always wins over theory, I must obviously be missing something. Can somebody spot a problem in the following code and tell me why it is possible at all that I can run into a deadlock?

```
async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(8)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    tasks = []

    #   Wrapper around the 'do_the_work' function to make sure that the
    #   semaphore is released in every case. In my opinion it should be
    #   impossible to leave this code without releasing the semaphore.
    #
    #   But as I can observe a deadlock in real life, I must be missing
    #   something!?
    async def task(**params):
        try:
            return await do_the_work(**params)
        finally:
            #   Whatever happens in do_the_work (that does not crash the whole
            #   interpreter), the semaphore should be released.
            sem.release()

    for params in jobs:
        #   Without the wait_for my code freezes at some point. The do_the_work
        #   function does not take too long, so the 10min timeout is
        #   unrealistic high and just a plausibility check to "proof" the dead
        #   lock.
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(sem.acquire(), 60*10)
        except TimeoutError as e:
            raise RuntimeError("Deadlock?") from e

        #   Start the task. Due to the semaphore there can only be 8 tasks
        #   running at the same time.
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(task(**params)))

        #   Check tasks which are already done for an exception. If there was
        #   one just stop immediately and raise it.
        for t in tasks:
            if t.done():
                e = t.exception()
                if e:
                    raise e

    #   If I reach this point, all tasks were scheduled and the results are
    #   ready to be consumed.
    for result in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
        handle_result(result)
```

Comment: You could print something in `task()`, and then try with/without `await asyncio.wait_for()`. It may be revealing. My guess is that it's `sem.acquire()` is what you should `await`, it's a coroutine, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) both tells it and shows it. Without the `await` the entire loop is synchronous and there's no way for the started tasks to complete.

Comment: Your code looks sound. But you didn't specify what `do_the_work` does. Maybe it occasionally takes a very long time due to a bug or unforeseen interaction with something else?

Comment: I would check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67981218/why-doesnt-this-asyncio-semaphore-implementation-work-with-aiohttp-in-python

maybe your problem is the `do_the_work`

Comment: maybe try this, `await sem.acquire()`   or change your desing to `async with sem:` just to to see the inpact https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it looks like a buggy behavior in `asyncio.Semaphore` itself - I just inspected that code, and I can't shake-off a feeling it can, somehow, get stuck if other concurrent tasks do not explicitly yield to the loop more often.

While that remains to be verified (and reported), the workaround for you now might be to add some explicit yields to the loop in your code, by adding some `await asyncio.sleep(0)` near that call to acquire.

Check if this makes your case better:

```
import asyncio, time
...
async def main():
    ...
    HARD_TIMEOUT = 60 * 10
    SOFT_TIMEOUT = HARD_TIMEOUT / 1000
    ...
    for params in jobs:

        start = time.monotonic()
        while True:
            try:
                await asyncio.wait_for(sem.acquire(), SOFT_TIMEOUT)
            except TimeoutError as e:
                if time.monotonic - start() > HARD_TIMEOUT:
                    raise RuntimeError("Deadlock?") from e
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
                continue
            break
        ...
```