# Deadlock with Python async processes and semaphore

Tags: python, python-asyncio, deadlock

Why does this deadlock?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio

async def _stream_subprocess(id: int, command: "list[str]"):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    await proc.wait()
    print(f"{id}: Done")


async def run(id: int, command: "list[str]"):
    print(f"{id}: Running")
    await _stream_subprocess(id, command)
    print(f"{id}: Throwing")

    raise RuntimeError("failed")


async def run_with_parallelism_limit(id: int, command: "list[str]", limit: asyncio.Semaphore):
    async with limit:
        print(f"{id}: Calling run")
        await run(id, command)
        print(f"{id}: Run finished")


async def main():
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1)
    await asyncio.gather(
        run_with_parallelism_limit(0, ["python", "--version"], sem),
        run_with_parallelism_limit(1, ["python", "--version"], sem),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
0: Calling run
0: Running
0: Done
0: Throwing
1: Calling run
1: Running
```

There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538602/deadlock-with-asyncio-semaphore) which is possibly related but it's difficult to tell since it isn't solved and the code is different.

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you put your type expressions in quotes? AFAIK, the only time you need to use type strings is for forward references.

Comment: You also need it for compatibility with older versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Put `return_exceptions=True` to [`asyncio.gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather):

```py
...

async def run_commands(commands: "list[list[str]]", num_jobs: int):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(num_jobs)
    tasks = [run_with_parallelism_limit(command, sem) for command in commands]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)  # <-- here!

...
```

Then the result is:

```
RUN
Running
Throwing
RUN
Running
Throwing
```

Comment: Ah interesting footgun. I still don't understand why it would deadlock though?

Comment: It seems to get stuck in `Runner._cancel_all_tasks()`.

Comment: Gave up trying to get this to work with Python and rewrote it with Deno which worked properly first time.